# How do i check for a specific value in a field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The javascript checks form values for not being empty

```
 if(!$('nradulti').value){ok=2;}
 if(!$('transport').value){ok=2;}
 if(!$('plata').value){ok=2;}

 if(ok==1){return true;}

 else if(ok==2){
      $('mesaj').innerHTML="
      <span class='notarea'>Please complete all fields.</span>";
      return false;
 }
```

I need to add a new variable called `spam` for captcha and check that it is equal to a certain number, e.g. "what's 2+2" and the script to proceed only if the number is 4

What line do i need to add please?

Thanks!

Comment: var spam; if(spam == '4') { ..... } be more specific pls, or show some php code, but the code you showed looks really bad :]

Comment: code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898181/how-do-i-add-anti-spam-to-a-phpjavascript-form-please

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a basic equality check.  I'm not exactly sure what framework your using, but given your other calls.

```
if(!$('spam').value == '4'){
   ok=2;
}
```

Comment: from what i gather in the code ok=2 leads to error and code ok=1 leads to form processing, i've added a link above, values are also defined in php, i only need to add this simple captcha. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your js file and declare the value for spam before this.
if($('spamInput_field_selector').value!=spam){ok=2}

Comment: i tried each one of these (spam question is what's 2+2)


`if(!$('spam').value!==4){ok=2;}`

`if(!$('spam').value!=='4'){ok=2;}`

`if(!$('spam').value!=4){ok=2;}`

`if(!$('spam').value!='4'){ok=2;}`

they all return ok=2, please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);

var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);

var spam = digit1 + digit2;

if(answer == ""){

    alert("Please add the numbers");

}else if(spam==answer){

    // call script  //
         }
```